# numpy huge error in rotational coordinate transformation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, coordinate-transformation

I would like to do a coordinate transformation in euclidian space by a rotation. This I would like to do by finding the matrices that align the current z axis towards a given input vector. At this moment these rotations do not give satisfactory output.

```
import numpy as np

vec_in = np.array([1*np.tan(np.pi/180*45), 1*np.tan(np.pi/180*45), 1]) 
vec_in /= np.linalg.norm(vec_in) #normalize, so we can use np.dot as scalar product
print vec_in

#find angles between vec_in and our x and y axis
#avoid inverse trigonometric functions, thereby increase accuracy
cosx = np.dot(vec_in, np.array([1,0,0]))
sinx = np.sqrt(1-cosx**2) 
cosy = np.dot(vec_in, np.array([0,1,0]))
siny = np.sqrt(1-cosy**2)

#turn around z to bring x fraction to zero
Rz = np.array([[cosx,-sinx,0], [sinx,cosx,0], [0,0,1]])
Rzi = np.linalg.inv(Rz)
print 'accuracy Rz\n', np.dot(Rz, Rzi)

#turn around y to align z to vector
Ry = np.array([[cosy,0,siny], [0,1,0], [-siny,0,cosy]])
Ryi = np.linalg.inv(Ry)
print 'accuracy Ry\n', np.dot(Ry, Ryi)

print np.dot(Ryi, np.dot(Rzi, vec_in)), '\tshould be [1,0,0]'
print np.dot(Rz, np.dot(Ry ,[0,0,1])), '\tshould be', vec_in
```

output is:

```
[ 0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027]
accuracy Rz
[[  1.00000000e+00   5.55111512e-17   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
accuracy Ry
[[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -7.70426082e-17]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
[-0.0067889  -0.13807119  0.99039904]   should be [1,0,0]
[ 0.47140452  0.66666667  0.57735027]   should be [ 0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027]
```

From the `np.dot(Rx,Rxi)` I conclude for now that the inverse matrices work well enough; just the actual result does not at all resemble what I would expect. Why? How would I get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first rotate the vector around y-axis so that it lies on xy-plane, which I called v1. Without normalization, v1 should be [sqrt(2), 1, 0]. (that accounts for `cosy` ,`siny`)

Then rotate v1 so that it also lies on xz-plane. so it's on the x-axis.

```
import numpy as np

vec_in = np.array([1*np.tan(np.pi/180*45), 1*np.tan(np.pi/180*45), 1]) 
vec_in /= np.linalg.norm(vec_in) #normalize, so we can use np.dot as scalar product
print vec_in

#find angles between vec_in and our x and y axis
#avoid inverse trigonometric functions, thereby increase accuracy

cosy = vec_in[0]/np.sqrt((vec_in[2]**2+vec_in[0]**2)) 
siny = np.sqrt(1-cosy**2)

#turn around y to align z to vector
Ry = np.array([[cosy,0,siny], [0,1,0], [-siny,0,cosy]])
Ryi = np.linalg.inv(Ry)
print 'accuracy Ry\n', np.dot(Ry, Ryi)

v1 = Ry.dot(vec_in) #z = 0
cosx = v1[0]/np.sqrt((v1[1]**2+v1[0]**2)) 
sinx = np.sqrt(1-cosx**2)

#turn around z to bring x fraction to zero
Rz = np.array([[cosx,-sinx,0], [sinx,cosx,0], [0,0,1]])
Rzi = np.linalg.inv(Rz)
print 'accuracy Rz\n', np.dot(Rz, Rzi)


print np.dot(Rzi, np.dot(Ry, vec_in)), '\tshould be [1,0,0]'
```

Comment: Your code yields the correct solution. Despite your description, you still use rotations around z and y which in this very case does not matter for the given example vector. I intended to turn around other axis and orders, basically following the same idea. The difference are the angles `cosx`, `sinx` - how would you propose to calculate them given an arbitrary `vec_in`?

Comment: Hi, I modified the code for general case. Just tested with some random `vec_in` by hand.

Comment: This works. I apparently calculated the wrong angles. Thank you for your help!